# Horizontal and vertical tangents to a parametric curve

Tags: calculus, parametric

I'm not sure what my procedure should be when solving this problem:

1. find all points with a horizontal tangent
2. find all points with a vertical tangent
3. find all inflection points

$$x(t) = \sin(t),\quad y(t)= t $$

When trying to solve these kinds of problems what steps should I take? I know that $x'(t) = \cos(t) $ and $y'(t) = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

By chain rule you have that
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}.
$$
So
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\cos t}.
$$
Can you take it from there?

Comment: oh! so it's the derivative of the y function, over the derivative of the x function to get to get $dy/dx$. Then set that equal to zero so $$ 0 = 1/cost $$. And that will get me my tangent?

Comment: @MathStruggler Setting it equal to $0$ will give you the horizontal tangents (if there are any).  Finding where the denominator is $0$ will give you vertical tangents, and inflection points are given by the second derivative.

Comment: You can also find vertical tangents by solving for $\frac{dx}{dy}=0,$ where $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{\frac{dx}{dt}}{\frac{dy}{dt}} =\cos t.$